# Get specific value from table A and copy that result into Table B?

Tags: sql

is there a way to get the result from a query and copy that result to a different table in a specic column.

here is what i have so far

```
//get CONTACT_ID from RETAILER_ID and create some loop that goes through all CONTACT_ID values and execute the queries below:

select CSN from CONTACTS where CONTACT_ID = '103309';
```

The above query gets the CSN value from CONTACTS table and i want to execute something below:

```
update RETAILER_CONTACTS set columnB = new CSN where CONTACTS_ID='103309';
```

I will need to do this for every single record in the RETAILER_CONTACTS hence why i need to execute the above in some loop that goes through each CONTACTS_ID i find from the below query:

Select CONTACT_ID from RETAILER_ID;

Thanks in advance

Comment: If `CSN` is logically a property of a `CONTACT`, then it shouldn't be a column in `RETAILER_CONTACTS` at all. Look up [Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), and specifically, update anomalies.

Comment: they need teh CSN value to be in the RETAILER_CONTACTS purely for indexing

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I've understood what you want to do, but most of the time, a desire to use loops in SQL is a sign of trouble. I think you can do what you want by something like:

```
update RETAILER_CONTACTS 
set columnB = CSN
from RETAILER_CONTACTS RC, 
     CONTACTS C, 
     RETAILERS R
where C.CONTACT_ID = '103309'
and   C.CONTACT_ID = RC.CONTACT_ID
and   C.RETAILER_ID = RC.RETAILER_ID
```

Comment: Looks interesting. im only dealing with two tables called Contacts and the other called RETAILER_CONTACTS.

both tables have a CONTACTS_ID and RETAILER_CONTACTS has the CSN column and i wish to copy the CSN from CONTACTS_ID into columnB from the RETAILER_CONTACTS table

Comment: update RETAILER_CONTACTS
set RC.columnB = C.CSN
from CONTACTS C, RETAILER_CONTACTS RC
where RC.CONTACTS_ID = C.CONTACTS_ID;